# Download excel file using javascript from aspnet-core api controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

My [excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7dBy.png) is corrupted. I tried converting to bytearray and using other types but to no avail.

I returned this from the API:

```
return File(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
```

AJAX Call:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Excel/DownloadExcel',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form').serialize()
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data],
                        {type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" }));
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myfile.xlsx';
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        })
        .fail(function (response) {
            displayErrorMessage(response.status, response.responseText);
        });
});
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The excel file is downloaded but corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround like below:

1.Model:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Export" />
</form>
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var data = $('#form').serialize();
        console.log(data);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/DownloadExcel',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location = '/Home/Download';
            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

3.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadExcel(List<UserInfo> list)
{
    list = new List<UserInfo>() { 
        new UserInfo(){ UserName="aa",Age=23},
        new UserInfo(){ UserName="ab",Age=24},
        new UserInfo(){ UserName="ac",Age=23}
    };
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        workSheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(list, true);
        package.Save();
        TempData["file"] = package.GetAsByteArray();
        return Ok();
    }         
}
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Download()
{
    byte[] data = TempData["file"] as byte[];
    return File(data, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "myfile.xlsx");                  
}
```

4.Result:
[image]