# How to do loading prompt show and hide when upload, generate and download file in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can upload an Excel file use `ExcelDataReader` and download Excel file use NPOI library. `btnSubmit` button is disabled when click for upload, stays disabled download Excel successfully. Excel file download is successful, but `btnSubmit` not changed and `INotifyService` is not working, refresh the page `INotifyService` works and shows notification. `INotifyService` added ctor and do dependency injection, works another pages.

`.cshtml` markup:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" />
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">select file</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 right">
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="disableButton()" asp-controller="Files" asp-action="ExcelFileReader" asp-route-requestID="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableButton() {
        document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('btnSubmit').value="loading....";        
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }      
</script>
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExcelFileReader(IFormFile file, Guid requestID)
{
    CurrentUser currentUser = _currentUserService.OnlineUser();

    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

    var uploadDirectory = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\wwwroot\\Uploads";

    var fileNameWithDate = $"{currentUser.CompanyName}_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}_{file.FileName}";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadDirectory, fileNameWithDate);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {                    
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {                        
            byte[] byteArray;                        

            var workbook = new NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook();
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Worksheet1");

            var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

            headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("PozNo");
            headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Leng");
            headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Count");
            headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Failed Reason");

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.Write(memoryStream);
                byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
                
            _notifyService.Success($" successfully added");
                
            return File(byteArray, "application/vnd.ms-excel", $"Failed{file.FileName}.xls");
        }
    }            
}
```

I want `btnSubmit` button to change and notification show after Excel file has been downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Because form submit doesn't have a response so that we couldn't have a callback to change the button status in js. Here's a [high voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374677) which mentioned:

> When you post a form, the form inputs are sent to the server and your
> page is refreshed - the data is handled on the server side. That is,
> the submit() function doesn't actually return anything, it just sends
> the form data to the server.

But in that answer it used a 3rd party library, so I prefer to use default ajax form submit instead. But we would run into another question is that we are trying to `return File()` directly and trigger a download in the client browser, but ajax can't do it for us directly. So I found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65550335) which manually create a `<a>` tag and click it via js to start the file downloading. Here's my test and it worked well.

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        FileModel model = new FileModel { Id = "222"};
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExcelFileReaderAsync(IFormFile file, Guid requestID)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
        var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
        return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
    }
}

public class FileModel {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

@model WebAppMvc.Controllers.FileModel

 @* asp-action="ExcelFileReader" asp-controller="File" *@
<form method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" />
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">select file</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 right">
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
            @* onclick="disableButton()" *@
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function disableButton() {
            alert(1);
            document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('btnSubmit').value = "loading....";
            alert(2);
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
        $('#myForm').submit(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('btnSubmit').value = "loading....";

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:7064/file/ExcelFileReader',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').value = "Upload";

                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
                    document.body.append(a);
                    a.click();
                    a.remove();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

[image]